# Establishing a tftp connection between windows and ubuntu

Tags: php, ftp, tftp

I want to have my files transfered from windows to ubuntu and that too through a code for tftp client in php. I found the whole dedicated library for the ftp connection but I am not able to find the same for the tftp connection.

Can I use the ftp library for the tftp also by just changing the port from "21" to "69" as "69" is the port on which tftp services work? or do i need to do something else?

*The function for the ftp connection is like `ftp_connect()` where the host and port details have to be given*

Comment: Did you try using that library with some code of yours? Found errors?

Answer (score 0):

No, tftp and ftp are completely two different protocols (which even use a completely different network protocol - udp for tftp and tcp for ftp).

You can use PHP's [FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) library for your FTP needs.